# What is "Brimsnapping"?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac

I've seen various references to a glitch that can make the Brimstone item more powerful - what is this glitch?

Comment: What references?  Where?  This has the exact same issues as the previous question: you make a claim, but there's nothing that backs it up.

Comment: @Frank I actually thought the previous question was useful, and deserved to keep existing.  Perhaps it should more explicitly refer to Brimsnapping, though.

Comment: It might have.  The asker self deleted it, however.  In any case, questions need to be able to stand on their own.  You're making a claim here, that there's a glitch.  Where's the reference?  Did you play the game and notice something?  I'm not saying we're going to delete the question, but self answering a question does not absolve it of having to meet the quality standards.  You still have to have a question that's a valid question, all by itself.

Comment: @Brilliand I deleted the previous question, as it turns out it is not a relevant issue in Rebirth and thus has no value.

Comment: @MadMAxJr You're probably not the only person who thought brimsnapping was relevant to Rebirth - it's worth keeping it on the record that it isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you fire a Brimstone charge, you can keep tapping the arrow key rapidly to fire the Brimstone beam repeatedly without needing to recharge - this is known as "Brim snapping".  The additional blasts won't appear on the screen, although they will still deal damage. (Source: http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Thread:41988)

In "The Binding of Isaac: Rebirth", brim snapping is no longer possible - the glitch has been fixed. (Source: http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/The_Binding_of_Isaac:_Rebirth)